# Present placeholder when there is no data in collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to display a `Text` widget when the collection is empty. However I never can meet the condition to display `Text('No Events :(');` even when my collection is empty. I presume it's a dart syntax error?

```
 Container(
                  height: 400,
                   // width: 500,
                    child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Events').where("bandId", isEqualTo:identifier ).snapshots(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

                        if (!snapshot.hasData)
                          return new Text('No Events :(');
                        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                          case ConnectionState.waiting:
                            return new Text('Loading...');
                          default:
                            return new ListView(
                              children: snapshot.data.documents
                                  .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {

                                return  Dismissible(
                                  key: new Key(document.documentID),
                                  onDismissed: (direction){
                                    Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
                                      DocumentSnapshot snapshot=
                                          await transaction.get(document.reference);
                                          await transaction.delete(snapshot.reference);


                                    });
                                    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Event Deleted");
                                  },

                                  child: CustomCard(
                                    event: document['event'],
                                    location: document['location'],
                                    service: document['service'],
                                    date: document['date'],
                                  ),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            );
                        }
                      },
                    )),
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a syntax error.
You can not use 
new Text("Something");
new ListView( 
//
)
You have to specify a Widget which support Children.
You can use Column for displaying multiple Widgets.

Reason: You are specifying If and Switch case.
I would suggest cover your logic inside Switch case only or in If-Else condition.

```
Container(
  height: 400,
  // width: 500,
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('Events').where("bandId", isEqualTo:identifier ).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      return new Column(
        children: [
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          new Text('No Events :('),
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
              new Text('Loading...');
          default:
            new Container(
              childe: ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.documents
                .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  return  Dismissible(
                    key: new Key(document.documentID),
                    onDismissed: (direction){
                      Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
                        DocumentSnapshot snapshot=
                            await transaction.get(document.reference);
                            await transaction.delete(snapshot.reference);
                        });
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Event Deleted");
                    },
                    child: CustomCard(
                      event: document['event'],
                      location: document['location'],
                      service: document['service'],
                      date: document['date'],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
        }
      ]),
    },
  )
);
```

Comment: thanks but that doesn't compile. The above Container is in a `Column`

Comment: for the 'if` `This requires the --control-flow-collections experiment to be enabled'` when I hover over red line. The output is Error: `Unexpected token 'if'.
                        if (!snapshot.hasData)` and for the switch keyword `Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'switch'.
                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {`

Comment: Column children expect widgets?

Comment: Yes, Column children expect Widgets.

I see your code. That is not wrapped with Column.
If you wrap entire code in Column and add children to only parent Widgets that will not work.

You have to children whenever you want to multiple widgets one by one.
You can use Column, Row, ListView to wrap your multiple widgets.

Comment: Did you see diff what I changed in your code?
I've added parent Column that contain children.
If you direct add If_else condition it will give you error as Unexpected Token If.

Comment: I've copied and pasted your code. It doesn't compile.

Comment: this is the gist https://gist.github.com/horgag1/289d01e0e5b8fb71f746b1e930378c81